# Validation on each element after removing the section jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do validation on remove button. I have a form which has a bootstrap clone function which duplicate the same section.

**This is my html**

```
      <div id="taskForm">
            <div class="form--group clearfix">
                          <label class="text-left">Name</label>
                          <input class="thename" name="name[]" type="text" value="" />
                          <label>Date of birth</label>
                          <input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" value="" />
                          <span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
                <div class="remAdd"><a class="removeButton" href="javascript:;"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form--group clearfix hide" id="taskTemplate">
                          <label class="text-left">Name</label>
                          <input class="thename" name="name[]" type="text" value="" />
                          <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label>
                          <input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" value="" />
                          <span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
                    <div class="remAdd"><a class="removeButton" href="javascript:;"></a></div>
            </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="addButton">Add Child</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="stepbirth" class="btn disabled">Next</a>
    </div>

<style>
 .disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #999;
}
</style>
```

Duplicate function is working fine.
I have validation on each class element which checks for all input.
When user fill in first input elements if both condition achieve it remove the disabled class from the button which is perfect, same as second elements. But the issue occurs when user fill the wrong data in any of above form--group and then remove this group so my function does not validate the previous form--group like if in previous form--group meet the both condition so Next button should remain enabled.

**Here is my JS**

This function clone the form--group and i tried to put validation on remove button to check previous form--group meet the correct condition.

```
//Bootstrap add remove section
$('#taskForm')
// Add button click handler
.on('click', '.addButton', function() {
  added++;  
  var $template = $('#taskTemplate')
      $clone    = $template
            .clone(true,true)
            .removeClass('hide')
            .removeAttr('id')
            .insertBefore($template)
   })
})
// Remove button click handler
.on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.form--group');
    $row.remove();
    var lastObj = $(this);
    var parent = lastObj.parent();
    var structure = parent.closest(".form--group");
    if (structure.find(".the").val().length > 1 && structure.find(".date_of_birth").val().length == 10) {
      alert('1');
      $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
    } 
    else {
        $("#stepbirth").addClass("disabled");
    }
})
```

**And this function validates on keyup change and DOMSubtreeModified**

```
//Step 1 validation
$('html').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function (event) {
 var structure = $(event.target).closest(".form--group");
 structure.find(".thename, .date_of_birth, .stepbirthVal").on("keyup change DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
   if (structure.find(".thename").val().length > 1 && structure.find(".date_of_birth").val().length == 10 ) {
     $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
   } else {
       $("#stepbirth").addClass("disabled");
   }
 });
});
```

This function is working fine, only i am not able to validate on remove button.

**With this function i show error message on date of birth field.**

```
////Date of birth validation
function dateOfBirth(inputid)
{
  var DoB = []; 
  $(".date_of_birth").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().trim();
    if (value.length)
      DoB.push($(this).val());
  });
var stepVar = DoB;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
  //GET JSON from Validation.php and extract the nodes
  var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
  var parseJson = JSON.parse(response);
  var resultCode = parseJson.code;
  var resultMessage = parseJson.message;

   //Show Validation Message
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(".stepbirthVal");
    parseJson.forEach(function (response, i) {
      return items[i].innerHTML = response.code === 0 ? response.message : "";
    });
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+stepVar",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I hope you guys understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which method are you using the validate the form?

Comment: I think you can add an event listener to delete button to re-trigger validate event again?

Comment: One problem is your inner event handler is actually adding a new event handler to `.removeButton, .thevoornaam ...` etc _every time_ there is a `keyup`, or a `click`, etc. If you type `Zain` in a name field, you will have 4x event handlers attached to your button, input fields, etc. You should set event handlers independent of user activity, eg define your event inner handler outside the first, and have it just call a function which evaluates the current state of things and adds/removes the `disabled`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Can you please give me example in code how can i achieve this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that is the only problem, but it is hard to tell because you have not shown us all your code (eg where is `dateOfBirth()`?  `.stepbirthVal`? Maybe those are not relevant (to this problem), in which case, remove them for this question.  Can you simplify your code to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Zain I tried to reproduce your issue locally, so I could troubleshoot, but bcs I don't have all your code, as described in my last comment, I can't.  I can't tell what is happening, so can't see the problem.  If you can create a simplified MCVE maybe we can help you.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i have created new thread, Can you please loot at here, i posted here in details where you can find all my code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57365472/bootstrap-clone-function-validation-on-remove-button-to-check-all-previous-field

Comment: @Zain Please don't create duplicate questions.  Are you asking the same question?  If yes, edit this question and update it, and delete your duplicate.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Can you please look into that thread, i will delete this one.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i have updated the code here and deleted the duplicated one. Is it clear for you now? What i want to achieve? Thanks